# Datanucleus JPA 2 Level 2 cache in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

What am I missing in the following configuration that my Datanucleus JPA 2 Level 2 cache is not using Google App Engine Memcache service? I am using the GAE 1.7.2 SDK.

In the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="5000" />
        <property name="datanucleus.datastoreWriteTimeout" value="10000" />
        <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.cacheName" value="someName"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="javax.cache"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Entity annotations contain:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
```

My WEB-INF/lib looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    27M Oct  3 16:13 appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   3.3M Oct  3 16:13 appengine-api-labs.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   5.0M Oct  3 16:13 appengine-endpoints.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   6.8K Oct  3 16:13 appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    45K Oct  3 16:13 asm-4.0.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   309K Oct  3 16:13 datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   246K Oct  3 16:13 datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   331K Oct  3 16:13 datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   1.6M Oct  3 16:13 datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   112K Oct  3 16:13 geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   5.2M Oct  3 16:13 gwt-servlet.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   196K Oct  3 16:13 jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20   7.9K Oct  3 16:13 jsr107cache-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    15K Oct  3 16:13 jta-1.1.jar
```

In the WEB-INF/lib directory, running:

```
for i in *.jar; do echo $i; jar -tf $i | grep Level2; done
```

yields:

```
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.2.jar
appengine-api-labs.jar
appengine-endpoints.jar
appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.2.jar
asm-4.0.jar
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar
datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar
datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar
datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar
org/datanucleus/cache/WeakLevel2Cache.class
org/datanucleus/cache/Level2Cache$PinnedClass.class
org/datanucleus/cache/AbstractLevel2Cache.class
org/datanucleus/cache/SoftLevel2Cache.class
org/datanucleus/cache/Level2Cache.class
org/datanucleus/cache/NullLevel2Cache.class
org/datanucleus/cache/JavaxCacheLevel2Cache.class
geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
jsr107cache-1.1.jar
jta-1.1.jar
```

which shows that org.datanucleus.cache.JavaxCacheLevel2Cache is present in datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar. Yet, when I try to access entities that have been persisted before this cache was enabled, I get the following error on the server side.

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Level 2 Cache "javax.cache" is registered to use class "org.datanucleus.cache.JavaxCacheLevel2Cache" yet this is not found. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
```

Further down the exception stack trace, I find:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/Caching
    at org.datanucleus.cache.JavaxCacheLevel2Cache.<init>(JavaxCacheLevel2Cache.java:63)
```

Now, that is clear but where can I find this javax.cache.Caching? Which JAR should I need to include in the classpath? A cursory Google search does not immediately answer my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Added http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/cache/cache-api/0.5/cache-api-0.5.jar. It contains javax.cache.Caching but now I have a different error:
`
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CachingProviders found in classpath.
`
Is it really this difficult to use the Level 2 cache on the App Engine with JPA (or even JDO)?

Comment: I've used GAE with L2 caching via memcached, with DN3.1, and "jcache" with "datanucleus-cache" in the classpath (after looking at other posts in SO) and all works for me

Comment: Thanks Neil. Could you confirm the exact datanucleus-cache JAR file that you have used in the war/WEB-INF/lib? Also, do you have a link to it? Which version of the AppEngine SDK did you use?

Comment: datanucleus-cache 3.1.1 with GAE 1.7.1

Comment: Okay, will try it out on GAE 1.7.2 (cannot go back to 1.7.1 now) and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "memcached" uses an old version of what will become the standard "javax.cache". DataNucleus 3.0 supports only this old version (with properties as you have). DataNucleus 3.1 supports **both** the old version of javax.cache and the most recent. To use the old version (i.e GAE memcached) with DN 3.1 you need to set the property **datanucleus.cache.level2.type** to *jcache*. See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/cache.html#jcache

Why you're using DataNucleus version 3.1.0-m3/m5 I've no idea when there are many releases since then!

Comment: thanks for letting me know. Will try this soon.

"Why you're using DataNucleus version 3.1.0-m3/m5 I've no idea when there are many releases since then!" -> because that's the version that was packaged with AppEngine 1.7.2 SDK. I am aware of the newer versions. I simply did not use them because I thought it might generate unforeseen inconsistencies and version incompatibilities with the AppEngine SDK 1.7.2 which is the latest.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I had indeed tried "jcache" in the past leading to the same problem. I suspect that I am missing some essential JARs. See my first comment to my original question.

Comment: you mean like "datanucleus-cache" which is clearly mentioned in the link I gave?

Comment: I've just advised Google of their unwise packaging choices, so hopefully they'll fix it by the next release

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in my last comment. When I used "jcache", the error was that "jcache" is not registered and that I needed to check my CLASSPATH.

Comment: Oh, ok. Noticed your comment now. Will check this and report back!

Comment: So, is this right?

<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.cacheName" value="someName"/>
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="jcache"/>

If yes, the error I get now is:

Level 2 Cache "jcache" is not registered. Please check your CLASSPATH and specification.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Level 2 Cache "jcache" is not registered. Please check your CLASSPATH and specification.

Comment: And if you meant the cache type should be "datanucleus-cache", then I get the same error: Level 2 Cache "datanucleus-cache" is not registered. Please check your CLASSPATH and specification.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Level 2 Cache "datanucleus-cache" is not registered. Please check your CLASSPATH and specification.

Comment: Thanks for prodding Google. They really ought to get their packaging right. I hope the 1.7.3 will fix it.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Ok, so which version of datanucleus-cache should I download? The latest? Would that be fine with the other slightly older JARs in the AppEngine SDK? Is this going to solve the issue with javax.cache.Caching class not found? I could re-download it from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/cache/cache-api/0.5/cache-api-0.5.jar but then there is the error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CachingProviders found in classpath.

Comment: 3.1.x versions of datanucleus-cache go with DN 3.1. All of your errors are caused by not having that in the CLASSPATH

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did test with datanucleus-cache 3.1.x once and it threw the same error. Perhaps, this was because the rest of the JARs were the old ones packaged with the Google AppEngine SDK?

Comment: Okay, it is solved now with datanucleus-cache-3.1.1.jar and GAE 1.7.2. Thanks.

Comment: javax.cache doesn't work in 3.1.1. It complains of missing class: javax.cache.Caching. jcache does work, however.

Comment: @DataNucleus - could someone please update this answer with the correct stanzas for Maven for GAE SDK 1.8.8 and the required versions for DataNucleus?

Comment: DataNucleus documentation for v3.1 is where anyone using DataNucleus should look (what this user is using); we don't go around backdating answers to people's questions on Stackoverflow; that's the point of documentation