# What is the correct settings to enable JPA Level 2 Caching?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, datanucleus, jcache

I am trying to figure out how to configure JPA 2.0 to use Memcache as the Level 2 cache in Google App Engine 1.8.7.

I have found [instructions that are a year old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719907/datanucleus-jpa-2-level-2-cache-in-google-appengine) and they don't work now.

#### Here is the error(s) that I am getting:

When I use `<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="jcache" />` I get the following error:

With core `3.1.4` / cache `3.1.2`:

> [INFO] Caused by: net.sf.jsr107cache.CacheException: Could not find
>   class: 'ri.cache.BasicCacheFactory'

With core `3.1.2` / cache `3.1.2`:

> [INFO] Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException:
>   Level 2 Cache "jcache" is registered to use class
>   "org.datanucleus.cache.jcache.JCacheLevel2Cache" yet this is not
>   found. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.

I haven't been able to figure out what to add where to resolve either issue.

When I use `<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="javax.cache" />` I get the following error:

> [INFO] Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException:
>   Level 2 Cache "javax.cache" is registered to use class
>   "org.datanucleus.cache.JavaxCacheLevel2Cache" yet this is not found.
>   Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.

I have tried the following settings in my `persistence.xml` and neither works:

Here are my relevant configuration settings:

#### persistence.xml

```
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.name" value="entitycache" />
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="javax.cache" />
```

and

```
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.name" value="entitycache" />
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="jcache" />
```

#### pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <resteasy.version>3.0.5.Final</resteasy.version>
    <jackson.version>2.2.3</jackson.version>
    <gae.version>1.8.7</gae.version>
    <gae-runtime.version>1.8.0</gae-runtime.version>
    <gae.home>/Users/jhr/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.8.7/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.7
    </gae.home>
    <datanucleus.version>3.1.2</datanucleus.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-cache</artifactId>
    <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### WEB-INF/lib

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   249K Nov 16 03:07 datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   338K May 17  2013 datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff    44K Dec  4 00:24 datanucleus-cache-3.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   1.7M Nov 16 03:07 datanucleus-core-3.1.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   188K Mar 14  2013 datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jhr  staff   7.9K Dec  4 01:22 jsr107cache-1.1.jar
```

#### What do I have to add/delete/modify to get this to work?

Comment: You don't post stack traces so give no idea where those exceptions come from. The JCache class is clearly in datanucleus-cache jar, and the class is https://sourceforge.net/p/datanucleus/code/HEAD/tree/platform/cache/trunk/src/java/org/datanucleus/cache/jcache/JCacheLevel2Cache.java  This is all defined in documentation at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/cache.html#jcache   The log would also tell you what is registered in the CLASSPATH etc.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12722764/2099217) you referenced, App Engine implements the 'old' JSR107 interface, which Datanucleus 3.1+ supports by setting the following property in persistence.xml / jdoconfig.xml:

```
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="jcache" />
```

(See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/cache.html#jcache)

You also need to add the following Maven dependencies:

```
<!-- JSR 107 API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- App Engine Memcache JSR 107 implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-jsr107cache</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Datanucleus cache extension to use a JSR 107 implementation as L2 cache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-cache</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Based on the information you provided, you were probably lacking the second one?